# How to data bind a field in formtastic page for knockoutjs

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, knockout.js, formtastic

Im trying to implement knockoutjs in my formtastic page. How can i bind data to a scaffold edformtastic erb page.

This is how i tried it. But didn't work

```
 <%= f.input :name, :data=>{:bind=>'value: name'} %>
```

my javascript

```
this.name = ko.observable("Bert");
```

Comment: that's not what i need. i need to implement knockoutjs in erb page

Comment: Please comment why a negative was given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how knockoutjs works, but for the formtastic part, you should do this:

```
<%= f.input :name, :input_html => {"data-bind" => "value: name" } %>
```

I'm not the one who voted down. ;-) (I'll vote up).